# RecyclerView show data from 2 different layouts

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I am using the following `code` in **Adapter** class to `show data` in a *RecyclerView*, but now I would like to show data from some other `ArrayList` in a **same** RecyclerView (at `some positions` like: 1st position and 6th position) using different layout.

That *different layout* (assume: **another_layout.xml**) contains *2 TextViews* and *an Image*, also want to implement **click** on listener for that *layout* too..

```
    @Override
    public PlaylistCardAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // inflate a card layout
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.youtube_video_card, parent, false);
        // populate the viewholder
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RecyclerView for more than one layout
1. Override getItemViewType(int position) method
e.g I have two layouts layout1 and layout2.I want layout1 at the top and then layout2. So getItemViewType would be something like this

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if(position == 0){    //for layout1
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 2;        //for layout2
    }
}
```

2. Different viewholder for each layout like this

```
class ViewHolder_LayoutOne extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView name;
    //Constructor
}

class ViewHolder_LayoutTwo extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView name;
    //Constructor
}
```

3. Inflate different layouts according to the position

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = null;
    if(viewType == 1){

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_layout_one,parent,false);
        vh = new MyViewHolder_LayoutOne(view);
    }else if(viewType == 2){

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_layout_two,parent,false);
        vh = new MyViewHolder_LayoutTwo(view);
    }
    return vh;
}
```

4. Bind your views as per the position

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    switch(getItemViewType(position)){

        case 1: //for layout 1
            ((ViewHolder_LayoutOne)holder).name.setText("");
            break;

        case 2:// for layout 2
            ((ViewHolder_LayoutTwo)holder).name.setText("");
            break;
    }
}
```

5.Now Most important getItemCount() method //return the number of views

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return toptitles.length + 1; 
   // as i have only layout at the top and the remaining size equals the length of the array toptitles.So the overall length would be 
   //number of views of layout1 + number of views of layout2
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I tried the way you mentioned me, but I am getting issues / errors at many places in my Adapter class, can you make modifications in my existing Adapter class ...  which one I posted above

Comment: take a look at this (udacity popular movie application project)https://github.com/gosemathraj/Cinema/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/gosemathraj/cinema/adapters/RecyclerViewCustomAdapter.java

Comment: for every 3rd position your getItemViewType just check for position like this if((position + 1) % 4 == 0){ return 1;}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130533/discussion-between-android-jack-and-sophie).

Answer (score 0):

you can override **getItemViewType**, and use different ViewHolder for different layout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override **getItemViewType** like this :

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      Add your condition and return viewType(Constant)
    }
```

Now, Check for viewType and retrun viewHolder accordingly.

```
    @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
          if (viewType == VIEWHOLDER1) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.layout1, parent, false);
                return new ViewHolder1(v);
          }else if(viewType == VIEWHOLDER2){
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.layout2, parent, false);
                return new ViewHolder2(v);
          }
        }
```

Now, Check for instance of viewHolder

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         if (holder instanceof ViewHolder1) {
             Show values in UI accordingly.
         }else if(holder instanceof ViewHolder2){
             Show values in UI accordingly.
         }
}
```

Comment: ohk... getItemViewType(...) what exactly I need to write... my logic is to show data from different layout in 1st and 6th position

Comment: In your case return position from getItemViewType and in onCreateViewHolder check for viewType using if-else OR switch and accordingly return ViewHolder.

Comment: I tried the way you mentioned me, but I am getting issues / errors at many places in my Adapter class, can you make modifications in my existing Adapter class ... which one I posted above

Answer (score 0):

You can set the type you want in getItemViewType(int position) with the layout you want. And onCreateViewHolder you can check viewType and inflate the row accordingly.

[here is an example.](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView)